# How to define true as false and vice versa?

Tags: c#, boolean

One of the first things you learn in C is that you can define `true` as `false` and `false` as `true`

I wonder, is it possible to define `true` as `false` and vice versa in C#?

Is it possible to modify other types like in the question above?

#### Example

This is how I want it to work.

```
if(false)
{
    // this will always be executed
}

if(true)
{
    // this will never be executed
}
```

Comment: That's the weirdest question I have ever seen. using `!false` is not enough?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Not possible, perhaps you'd prefer to use C++ where things like this are allowed

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia C++ has keywords for `true` and `false`, so I don't think you are right about that.

Comment: Also, if you did succeed in doing this, your code would be horrible to read, understand, and debug.

Comment: Don't forget about [FILE_NOT_FOUND](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx) but seriously this would be an extremely profound violation of the principle of least astonishment

Comment: The asker might wanted to do the following question: "how can i check if a boolean has the 'false' value.

Comment: @LuisFilipe I don't think so, based on his code block he wants `if(false)` to evaluate to true so that `// do stuff` is executed. Still makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Nah, I know it's possible in C (#define FALSE TRUE) at least so wondered if anyone knew if it was possible in C# as well. I will never use it.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder But WHY?

Comment: @tnw, because: why not?

Comment: @crashmstr [It's easier than you'd think in C++](http://ideone.com/kFS5vI) :)

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder Because if you want an if-statement to evaluate to true always, why have it at all? Why not just write `if(true)`? Why not just eliminate it entirely? It's also confusing and makes your code difficult to read and understand. I could go on. There's scores of reasons why not and literally none why you should.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a *practical* programming problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  static void Main()
  {
     bool \u0066alse = true;
     if (\u0066alse)
     {
        // Do code here:
     }
  }
```

or how about this:

```
  static void Main()
  {
     bool \u0066alse = true;
     if (@false)
     {
        // Do code here:
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to redefine `true` as `false` and `false` as `true`.
`true` and `false` are properties of `System.Boolean`, and you can not change this.

But, if you want to write some code for fun, you can define True and False in a class and use it.

```
using System;

public static class I
{
    public static Boolean True { get { return false; } }

    public static Boolean False { get { return true; } }
}
```

Then, in your code

```
if (I.True)
{
    // never work
}

if (I.False)
{
    // do stuff
}

if (MyFunction() == I.False)
{
    // do stuff when MyFunction return true
}
```

That's not exactly the same writing, but it can interfere with people reading the code...